# Using \tag with amsthm environments?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I would like to custom tag theorems, similar to the way `\tag` lets me custom tag equations in a math environment. How should I go about doing so? [The `amsthm` package documentation is silent on doing something like this.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}[article]

\begin{equation}
    a + b = c \tag{A1}\label{A1}
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}[My important theorem.]
    The universe will cease to exist tomorrow.
\end{theorem}

I would like to tag My important theorem as ``T1'', just like how I tagged \eqref{A1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of interface are you after? Or are you okay with anything?

Comment: @Werner Could you explain what you mean by interface?

Comment: Do you want something like `\begin{taggedtheorem}[..] ... \theoremtag{T1} \end{taggedtheorem}`, or would the simpler `\settheoremtag{T1} \begin{taggedtheorem}[..] ... \end{taggedtheorem}` suffice? Or something else altogether...?

Comment: I was thinking the second (simpler) option, because then I can easily extend the solution to tag other environments as well (remarks, definitions, etc.).

Comment: The documentation for `amsthm` is undergoing revision.  Is the form of the output shown in the answers acceptable for the purpose you have in mind?  If so, it can be considered as a candidate for the `thmtest.tex` file that accompanies the documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The form of the output in the answers is exactly what I was hoping it would look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following might suffice, although the interface is not as ideal as the regular equation `\tag`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settheoremtag}[1]{% \settheoremtag{<tag>}
  \let\oldthetheorem\thetheorem% Store \thetheorem
  \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{#1}% Redefine it to a fixed value
  \g@addto@macro\endtheorem{% At \end{theorem}, ...
    \addtocounter{theorem}{-1}% ...restore theorem counter value and...
    \global\let\thetheorem\oldthetheorem}% ...restore \thetheorem
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a + b = c \tag{A1}\label{A1}
\end{equation}

\settheoremtag{T4}
\begin{theorem}[My important theorem]\label{thm:importantA}
    The universe will cease to exist tomorrow.
\end{theorem}

I would like to tag My important theorem as ``\ref{thm:importantA},'' just like how I tagged~\eqref{A1}.
Then there is also Theorem~\ref{thm:importantB}.

\begin{theorem}[My important theorem]\label{thm:importantB}
    The universe will cease to exist tomorrow.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set a theorem tag using `\settheoremtag{<tag>}`, which will then be used to set the numbering for the subsequent `theorem` environment. At `\end{theorem}`, the default settings are restored in order to allow for inter-mixing of regularly-numbered theorems together with fixed-tag ones.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your implementation! This is helpful in learning.

Answer (score 8):

Define a special form of theorem and use a new environment with an argument for setting the tag by redefining the `\the...` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % not mandatory, just to show it works also with it

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{taggedtheoremx}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{taggedtheorem}[1]
 {\renewcommand\thetaggedtheoremx{#1}\taggedtheoremx}
 {\endtaggedtheoremx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a + b = c \tag{A1}\label{A1}
\end{equation}

\begin{taggedtheorem}{T4}[My important theorem]\label{thm:importantA}
    The universe will cease to exist tomorrow.
\end{taggedtheorem}

I would like to tag My important theorem as ``\ref{thm:importantA},'' just like how I
tagged~\eqref{A1}. Then there is also Theorem~\ref{thm:importantB}.

\begin{theorem}[My important theorem]\label{thm:importantB}
    The universe will cease to exist tomorrow.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. What's the relationship between a newly created theorem environment, and the `\the...`

Comment: @user89 When LaTeX finds `\label` it uses the most recent counter that has been subject to `\refstepcounter`, in this case `taggedtheoremx`, using `\thetaggedtheoremx` that we have suitably redefined.